# Determine all group homomorphisms of the form $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{12}\to \mathbb{Z}_{30}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I have a quick question about the following problem:

> Determine all group homomorphisms of the form $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{12}\to \mathbb{Z}_{30}$.

I understand that $\phi(1)$ generates $\phi$, and since $|\phi(1)|$ divides both $12$ and $30$, then $|\phi(1)|=\left \{ 1,2,3,6 \right \}$. This is where I get confused: $|\phi(1)|=\left \{ 1,2,3,6 \right \}$ implies $\phi(1)=\left \{ 0,15,10,20,25 \right \}$ which are all in $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$. I don't understand this part...where did $0,15,10,20,25$ come from?

Comment: $\{0,5,10,20,25\}$ are all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$ of order 1,2,3, or 6.

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter Thank you for taking the time to answer very clearly. I understand now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{12}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ is determined by $\phi(1)$.

$\phi(12)=12\cdot\phi(1)\equiv_{30}0$, so you need to find all the $\phi(1)\in\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ such that $30\mid 12\cdot \phi(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Which elements $x \in \Bbb Z_{30}$ satisfy $6x = 0$?